# glCallList has no effect coding in JOGL

Tags: java, opengl, jogl, displaylist

Nothing shows up when I try and render my triangle using the display list. Can anyone tell me why?

inside the display() method, calling renderTriangle(gl, 100); directly works as expected, a triangle 200 pixels wide appears on the screen. But the gl.glCallList(list); call seems to have no effect. Nothing shows up on the screen at all.

For those unfamiliar with JOGL, here is the method call order. init, reshape, display, display, display...

Is my buildDisplayList method okay? Is the call to glCallList right? Am I meant to have any extra setup to make it work?

```
public class TriDemo extends GLJPanel implements GLEventListener {

private int list;

public TriDemo(GLCapabilities glCapabilities, int width, int height) {
    super(glCapabilities);
    this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    this.addGLEventListener(this);
}

private void renderTriangle(GL2 gl, float size) {
    gl.glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
        gl.glVertex3f(-1*size, -1*size, 0);
        gl.glVertex3f(1*size, -1*size, 0);
        gl.glVertex3f(0*size, 1*size, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
}

private void buildDisplayList(GL2 gl) {
    list = gl.glGenLists(1);
    gl.glNewList(list, GL_COMPILE);
        renderTriangle(gl, 100);
    gl.glEndList();
}

@Override
public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0.2f, 1);

    buildDisplayList(gl);
}

@Override
public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable drawable) { }

@Override
public void display(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();

    gl.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    gl.glColor3f(0, 1, 0);
    //renderTriangle(gl, 100);
    gl.glCallList(list);
}

@Override
public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable drawable, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    GLU glu = GLU.createGLU(gl);

    gl.glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    glu.gluOrtho2D(-width/2, width/2, -height/2, height/2);
    gl.glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();
    gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
}
```

}

Other class for a runnable example:

```
public class AppWindow extends JFrame {

public AppWindow() {
    super("Tri Test);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    GLProfile glProfile = GLProfile.getDefault();
    GLCapabilities glCapabilities = new GLCapabilities(glProfile);
    GLJPanel panel = new TriDemo(glCapabilities, 800, 600);
    FPSAnimator animator = new FPSAnimator(panel, 60);
    animator.start();
    this.getContentPane().add(panel);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new AppWindow();
}
```

Comment: First things first; did you call `glGetError` to check for errors?

Comment: Yes. I put calls to glGetError on either side of anything dealing with the display list parts. It always returned 0.

Comment: What's the value of "list"? Is it 0? There is a bug in your code or your driver is a bit broken, there is nothing wrong in JOGL with display lists, it just calls native OpenGL methods, it does nothing fancy. Please look at the examples in jogl-demos, I haven't succeeded in finding it but I'm almost sure that there is at least one example using display lists. Anyway, you shouldn't use display lists even in some code for old machines because there are tons of broken implementations and most modern drivers use static VBOs under the hood for display lists.

Comment: glGenLists correctly generates with no error and is non-zero. I'm guessing my driver is just bung. As far as I can see, my code is fine and follows the right structure. I guess I was just hoping some other eyes could see something I missed. glDrawArrays is working fine so am just using that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Your `buildDisplayList()` function is called before your viewport is ready. This is the reason why nothing is rendered on the screen. The 
`buildDisplayList()` should be called in the `display()` function i.e. after the viewport and GL initialization.